# How do you make a function using the if command for a range of values on R

Tags: r, if-statement, range

```
normal.con = function (x){

if (x<601){
    a = x * 0.01
}

else if (x>4000){
    a = 318 + ((x-4000)*0.12)
}

    return (a)
}
```

I would like to add another command to calculate 'a' if 600 < x < 4001. I attempted the following:

```
normal.con = function (x){
z = c (601,4000);

if (x<601){
    a = x * 0.01
}

else if (x == range (z)){
a = 118 + (x*0.1)
}

else if (x>4000){
    a = 318 + ((x-4000)*0.12)
}

    return (a)
}
```

But it gives a warning and a wrong answer

```
Warning message:
In if (x == range(z)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: How do you want the code to behave when `x=601` or `x=4000`? So far, your inequalities are strict.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question, @NicholasFlees. I want it to calculate a = 118 + (x*0.1). Thanks.

Comment: OK. Thought so. The solution below takes that into consideration.

Comment: What do you expect `x == range(x)` to do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the conditional statements so that they're a bit more reader-friendly.  You can implement the third condition as a double-conditional.

*If `x` is less than or equal to 600 calculate ...

If `x` is greater than or equal to 4000 calculate ...

If `x` is greater than 600 **AND** `x` is less than 4000, calculate ...*

```
normal.con <- function(x)
{
    y <- numeric(length(x))

    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      if(x[i] <= 600){
        y[i] <- x[i] * 0.01 
      } else if(x[i] >= 4000){
        y[i] <- 318 + ((x[i]-4000)*0.12)
      } else if(x[i] > 600 & x[i] < 4000){
        y[i] <- 118 + (x[i]*0.1)
      }
    }
    return(y)
}

> normal.con(c(100, 2000, 5000))
## [1]   1 318 438
```

**ADDED:** Just for fun, here are two other versions of the same function.  One, `normal.con2` uses `sapply`, and the other, `normal.con3` uses `lapply`.

```
normal.con2 <- function(x)
{
  ss <- sapply(x, function(y){
    if(y <= 600){ y * 0.01 }
    else if(y >= 4000){ 318 + ((y - 4000) * 0.12) }
    else if(y > 600 & y < 4000){ 118 + (y * 0.1) }
  })
  unlist(ss)  
}
# ---
normal.con3 <- function(x)
{
  ll <- lapply(x, function(y){
    if(y <= 600){ y * 0.01 }
    else if(y >= 4000){ 318 + ((y - 4000) * 0.12) }
    else if(y > 600 & y < 4000){ 118 + (y * 0.1) }
  })
  unlist(ll)
}
# ---
> x <- c(100, 2000, 5000)
> normal.con(x)
# [1]   1 318 438
> normal.con2(x)
# [1]   1 318 438
> normal.con3(x)
# [1]   1 318 438
```

The speed test results are interesting.  It seems `lapply` (`normal.con3`) is fastest in this situation, and `sapply` us quite a bit slower than the other two.

```
> list(for.loop = system.time({ replicate(1e5, normal.con(x)) }),
       sapply = system.time({ replicate(1e5, normal.con2(x)) }),
       lapply = system.time({ replicate(1e5, normal.con3(x)) }))
# $for.loop
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.985   0.000   1.524 
# 
# $sapply
# user  system elapsed 
# 4.393   0.000   4.307 
# 
# $lapply
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.480   0.000   1.404
```

Comment: Unfortunately it wont work with `normal.con(c(100,2000,5000))` like most functions in R, but the OP didn't explicitly ask for that explicitly.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this. `sapply` is great, and has a place, but the performance differences between using a scalar function and a vector function can be huge. Below a quick example: > fs<-function(pred,x) if(pred(x)) x else NA;    fv<-function(pred,x) ifelse(pred(x),x,NA); system.time(fv(function(x) x%%2 == 0,v))
   user  system elapsed
  0.762   0.014   0.778  system.time(sapply(v, fs, pred=function(x) x%%2 ==0))
   user  system elapsed
 10.563   0.519  11.092
identical(fv(function(x) x%%2 == 0, v), sapply(v, fs, pred=function(x) x%%2 ==0))
[1] TRUE

Comment: Sorry, what are you disagreeing with?

Comment: the comment you deleted, that said that was what `sapply` was for.

Comment: together with the example you had a bit ago using `sapply` and is no longer here

Comment: Oh.  Yeah.  I was catching heat for confining `x` to a length-one vector so I updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut()` to evaluate which case applies, then use `switch()` conditional on the result.

```
switch(cut(x,breaks=c(-Inf,600.999999,4000,Inf),labels=FALSE),
    x * 0.01,
    118 + (x * 0.1),
    318 + ((x - 4000) * 0.12))
```

See `?cut` for the definition of the break intervals - by default, these are `(a,b]`.

Answer (score 1):

A nested `ifelse` would be possible

```
normal.con <- function (x){
   ifelse(x < 601, x * 0.01, 
         ifelse(x > 4000, 318 + ((x-4000)*0.12), 118 + (x*0.1)))}

> normal.con(74)          #single value input
#[1] 0.74

> normal.con(c(1000,100,5000))         #multiple value input
#[1] 218   1 438
```

As @JPC noted in his comment, `ifelse` is vectorized while the normal `if ... else` statement is not. So you'll have performance advantage by using `ifelse`.

Update:

By the way, if you need more variability on the ranges (I think that was what @MrFlick assumed in his answer) you can easily achieve this by giving two more inputs to the `normal.con` function.

```
normal.con <- function(x, lower = 601, upper = 4000){
  ifelse(x < lower, x * 0.01, 
     ifelse(x > upper, 318 + ((x-4000)*0.12), 118 + (x*0.1)))}
```

This way, you have default values for a lower (601) and upper (4000) bound and you dont need to input them in the function:

```
> normal.con(c(100, 1000, 5000))      #uses the default ranges of 601 and 4000
#[1]   1 218 438
```

If you need to change the bounds, just pass the new values to `normal.con`:

```
> normal.con(c(100, 1000, 5000), 500, 7000)     #lower bound = 500, upper = 7000
#[1]   1 218 618
```

Comment: no need to use `return` in R for the most part. It returns your last evaluated statement, ala functional programming, so just don't assing it to `a` and that will do. +1 for using vector operations

Comment: @JPC i realized that after i posted the answer but was somehow reluctant to adjust it (will do so now)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't actually want to exclude cases where `x=601` or `x=4000` in this block of conditionals, you could do the following:

```
if (x < 601) {
    a = x * 0.01
} else if (x > 4000) {
    a = 318 + ((x - 4000) * 0.12)
} else {
    a = 118 * (x * 0.1)
}
```

The last `else` block will execute whenever the first two conditions are not met.

Comment: Unfortunately it wont work when `x` is a vector like most functions in R, but the OP didn't explicitly ask for that explicitly so perhaps it's not a problem.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. Good point. I was curious about the rationale for the downvote. Perhaps somebody else had the same thought as you but considered it more critical to the solution.

Comment: There are plenty of R functions that accept length-one vectors.  No big deal, and can easily be adjusted to accept longer vectors.

Answer (score -2):

I've created an overly complex solution that allows you to create a helper function to do an inline type of rang value finder. The ranger function takes the cut points you want to split on and then returns a function that will choose the value of the parameter based on which interval it falls. It primarily uses `findInterval` but unfortunately you inequalities don't exactly line up with how `findInterval` likes to do them so I had to do some fiddling.

```
#meta-helper function
ranger<-function(rng) {
    function(x, ...) {
        dots<-list(...)
        stopifnot(ncol(dots)==length(rng)+1)
        m<-findInterval(x, rng)+1
        ex<-match(x, rng);
        if (any(!is.na(ex))) {
            m[which(ex>1)]<-ex[which(ex>1)]
        }
        out<-rep(NA, length(x))
        for(i in seq_along(dots)) {
            out[m==i]<-rep(dots[[i]], length.out=length(x))[m==i]
        }
        out;
    }
}

#helper function
abc<-ranger(c(600,4000))

#implementation 1
x<-c(100,2000,5000)
a<-abc(x, 0.01, 0.1, 0.12)*x + abc(x, 0, 118, -162);
a;

#implementation 2
a<-abc(x, x * 0.01, 118 + (x*0.1), 318 + ((x-4000)*0.12));
a;
```

So while it may not be the best choice in this case, i might be useful if you have a bunch of different ranges or something like that.

Comment: Now i'm confused about the down votes. Which part of my answer is incorrect?

Comment: Downvotes do not necessarily indicate that the answer is incorrect, but that the answer is not useful. (I was not one of the downvoters.)